# Include custom node attributes in plot

Tags: graphviz, dot

I need to plot a DOT graph as SVG/PDF but would like to include the node attributes for each node. For example, on the plot:

```
strict digraph G {

  start -> a0;
  a0 -> a3;
  j0[name=asd, weight=2];
  a3 -> j0;
  j0 -> end;
}
```

how to include `name` and `weight` values under `j0`, like (e.g.):

```
strict digraph G {

  start -> a0;
  a0 -> a3;
  a3 -> "j0\nname=asd\nweight=2";
  "j0\nname=asd\nweight=2" -> end;
}
```

Comment: Both your graphs are valid Graphviz.  Not clear what you are looking for different from the second graph.

Comment: I'd like to plot something like the second graph (with all the node attribs showed) but from the first, where the attibs are just specified normally (instead of in the node name with is a bit cumbersome and error-prone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert all the node attributes and values into the **label** attribute (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/label/), instead of the node name.

```
strict digraph G {

  start -> a0;
  a0 -> a3;
  a3 -> j0
  j0 [label="j0\nname=asd\nweight=2"]
  j0-> end;
}
```

Giving:
[image]